# Package for Converting Time Series to be Stationary in R

Tags: r, time-series

Are there any packages in R out there that will do the work of transforming a uni-variate or bi-variate time series to be stationary?

Thanks; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a one for all package with a bunch of different functions to convert non stationary time series to stationary? No (As far as I know)

Its all about the data and figuring out what [method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2080/136596) would work.

To check if your time series is stationary - can try `box.test`, `adf.test` or `kpss.test`

---

Did you try `diff()`? [`diff`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/diff) calculates the differences between all consecutive values of a vector.

"One way to make a non-stationary time series stationary — compute the differences between consecutive observations. This is known as differencing." - from [link](https://otexts.org/fpp2/stationarity.html)

Another way would be `log()` transformation which is often used with `diff()`.

Other methods are square, log difference, lag. Could try different combinations of those techniques for example log square difference or try other things like Box-Cox transformations.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming this. I had an inkling of a thought that it's just a series of tests and transformations. Have a great day!